# No JSONFormatter works in Safari 8.0 on Yosemite

Tags: plugins, safari

I tried several JSONFormatter plugins to prettify the var_dump data from the framework laravel.

None of the plugins worked, though. I have no idea why. I tried everything, but it always gives me raw text instead of formatted text

Any ideas?

PS: For example, I tried this one: https://github.com/rfletcher/safari-json-formatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! The problem was hiding in my 'homestead.yaml' file. I had to turn this:

```
sites:
    - map: website.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Website/public
      hhvm: true
```

to this:

```
sites:
    - map: website.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Website/public
```

h `hhvm: true` was causing the problem. I removed it, backed up my database (gets deleted) and ran `vagrant provision {your vagrant-id}`

I don't know why, but now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I got that problem too. Although my json format is valid, the browser still does not show it in a pretty way.

Well, I translate my result using `Jsend` (https://github.com/shkm/JSend) and the returned result works fine in all browsers. I am not sure why but this is a viable option if you do not want to spend time investigating.

Comment: thanks, I will keep that in mind :) But the best way would be to find the cause of the problem. I mean, for others it works perfectly well.

Comment: Sure, if you find it out, share it with us :) I would be happy to know that